# How to get values only array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

`Array ( [0] => UK [1] => France [2] => USA )`  in these array get only values

like array(UK, France, USA) am trying like below,

```
$expression=array_values(array('0' => 'UK', '1' => 'France', '2' => 'USA')); 
var_dump($expression);
```

**OUTPUT PLAN:**

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "UK" [1]=> string(6) "France" [2]=> string(3) "USA" }
```

Can i get my desired output?

Comment: Simply use foreach loop and echo the variable.

Comment: you know array(UK, France, USA) is same as above

Comment: Using for loop i got output like UKFranceUSA, cant return array result.

Comment: array(UK, France, USA) and Array ( [0] => UK [1] => France [2] => USA ) are same

Comment: You have to understand how [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) in PHP works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read answer carefully.

```
$arr = array('UK', 'France', 'USA'); // It has 0 ,1 ,2 keys but you cannot see in the code`
```

But in browser you can see it.

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "UK" [1]=> string(6) "France" [2]=> string(3) "USA" }
```

Just use loop to print each country

```
foreach($arr as $country){
  echo $country."<br>";
}
```

You can understand it by below loop

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$country){
  echo "$k => $country"."<br>";  // Here $k is key like 0,1,2..
}
```

If you have array like below:-

```
$arr = array('uk'=>'UK', 'france'=>'France', 'usa'=>'USA')  // It has uk ,france ,usa keys
```

now `array_values($arr)` will give you output as below

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "UK" [1]=> string(6) "France" [2]=> string(3) "USA" }
```

It will remove all keys and regenerate index of key from 0.

**Refer below links to understand PHP array:-**

[Link1](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)

[Link2](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

[Link3](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_arrays.htm)

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
$out = array();

foreach($old_array as $new_value)  { //Where $old_array is the array you want to convert
array_push($out, $new_value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$expression=array_values(array('0' => 'UK', '1' => 'France', '2' => 'USA')); 
foreach($expression as $val) {
echo $val.",";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All PHP arrays have an internal index whether you attach one or not. So in your example even if you created an array using `$countries = array("USA", "UK", "France")` it would still output with indexes.

You can however ignore the indexes when your looping through it and only work with the values using a `foreach()` loop.

An example of such a loop would be...

```
foreach($expression as $index => $country) {
    echo($country . "<br />");
};
```

The above example will print each country on its own line. You can adapt it to suit whatever looping you need.

As a side note be aware that the index will commence from 0 so item 1 in the array will have an index of 0 and increment from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have this array.

```
Array ( [0] => UK [1] => France [2] => USA )
```

you have key and value assigned to it.

if you make another array like

```
array('UK','France','USA')
```

It is an associative array. Its the same as above.
[Read it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for more info

If you want to do operation with the array you can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) or other array related functions. So, first of all say what are you trying to accomplish with this one.